# Why duplication not follow path

Tags: bezier-curves, path

Im making duplication along the path. I have a mesh and a curve path. Selecting the mesh and curve i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and selected follow path. In Duplication i turn off speed. The mesh is not following the path in circular shape. Its twisted. I applied scale and rotation to both curve and mesh yet the result is twisted. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

**dupli error file**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your file, and just after removing the parent in "object > relations" and selecting again "cube.004" in that listbox, the parent is better:

[image]

something didn't update correctly during some previous operation, maybe.

edit: ok, it is nearly the same even with the new file.

this time, after re-applying the parent as above, you need to clear its origin.

[image]

Comment: Have u done other settings other than that my result is different the mesh going away from the curve

Comment: no, just opened the file, and tried to reassign that parent object....I tried again now.

Comment: Sorry i have send the wrong file. I have attach the new file (dupli error)

Comment: ok, I updated the answer

Comment: Yes thanks i send the wrong file before so i was getting different result. This is perfect now.